# Is it possible to change image from portrait to landscape on mobile devices using CSS?

Tags: css, image, squarespace

I've build a webpage on SquareSpace however it doesn't behave very well as the screen gets smaller. Image to the left and text to the right just bunch up, so on a tablet part of the image is cut off and the text looks squashed

What I'd like to have happen is that the portrait image changes to landscape and moves above the text. Is this possible using CSS?

Here's a link to the page in question: https://www.keoghmediation.com/home-3

Comment: With flexbox, you could use `flex-direction: row` in desktop mode, and then `flex-direction: column` in mobile mode. You could use a CSS media query to change the display setting  when the screen shrinks to a specific width. Not sure how much freedom you have to edit CSS with SquareSpace, though. CSS Grid works as well.     https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/media-queries-responsive-design-2018/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Will, I'll look into that. It is quite troublesome to add or edit CSS in SS and I'm a newbie to that platform so it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In your photo slider you have to different ids in the original home page and the new on (Home-3).

original home page

```
<div class="sqs-slide-layer full-width-height split-fifty" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1589588495048_236">
```

new home page-> home-3

```
<div class="sqs-gallery sqs-gallery-design-stacked" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1589588520313_119" style="height: 400.667px;">
```

Try to use the original id and see if that sorts things out for you. Maybe provide the css file to have a look at your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help Theodosis. SS is difficult to work with but they do allow a "CSS injection" section that I might be able to add configurations to. I can't edit existing CSS though, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to determine the screen size, like this:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}
```

and then use CSS to rotate an image, like this:

```
.my-image {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    /*float: left;*/
}
```

You can also try playing around with `float: left` if you want text to flow around the image.

More about media queries: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks Seano. I don't want to rotate the image, I want to change the dimensions. The images are originally landscape, however the way the homepage is set up the images are cropped to portrait dimensions. I want to change it so that on mobile devices it presents as landscape dimensions. Also, I don't want the text to flow around the image I just want it to move under the image :) Unfortunately, I don't think determining the screen size will fix the problem I have as that won't necessary shift the image and text the way I want